# Make background color to div tag

Tags: html, css

How to make background- color to whole text . I want to output like (using CSS).

[image]

```html
<div class="" style="background-color:red; clear: both;padding-top:10px;" id="test">
       <div style="float:left;">
              <input type="checkbox" class="chk" style="display: none;">
         </div>
          <div style="width:946px;">
            <div class="portlet-content" style="background-color:blue;">
               <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px; text-align: right; padding-left: 25px;" >
                    <b><span style="font-size:11.0pt">4)</span></b>
                    </div>
              <div style="float: left; width: 775px; word-wrap: break-word; text-align: justify;" >
                        <span style="font-size:12pt">
                            <span style="font-size:14.0pt">test content test content test content test content test content test content.</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How it possible in my case using css?

Comment: You're using `float`, so the container div doesn't expand to encompass its content. Research "clearing floats", or even better, "flexbox".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `overflow: auto` to the div with the red background:

```html
<div class="" style="background-color:red; clear: both;padding-top:10px;overflow:auto" id="test">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="chk" style="display: none;">
  </div>
  <div style="width:946px;">
    <div class="portlet-content" style="background-color:blue;">
      <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px; text-align: right; padding-left: 25px;">
        <b><span style="font-size:11.0pt">4)</span></b>
      </div>
      <div style="float: left; width: 775px; word-wrap: break-word; text-align: justify;">
        <span style="font-size:12pt">
                            <span style="font-size:14.0pt">test content test content test content test content test content test content.</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you float a child element, the parent's container collapses and acts as if the child didn't take up space.

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: auto` should do the trick if you add that property to your CSS for the `div`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code with clear div.

```
<div class="" style="background-color:red; clear: both;padding-top:10px;" id="test">
   <div style="float:left;">
          <input type="checkbox" class="chk" style="display: none;">
     </div>
      <div style="width:946px;">
        <div class="portlet-content" style="background-color:blue;">
           <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px; text-align: right; padding-left: 25px;" >
                <b><span style="font-size:11.0pt">4)</span></b>
                </div>
          <div style="float: left; width: 775px; word-wrap: break-word; text-align: justify;" >
                    <span style="font-size:12pt">
                        <span style="font-size:14.0pt">test content test content test content test content test content test content.</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both; display:block;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```